# The notation for the boundary of a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, manifolds-with-boundary

For a region $A$ in $n$space, we use the notation $\partial A$ to denote the boundary of the region $A$, but why we are using the symbol $\partial$, is there some connection between the partial derivatives and the boundary or is it just a notational thing?

Comment: see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46252/is-the-boundary-partial-s-analogous-to-a-derivative)

Comment: @Yassir No connection, just notation.

Comment: @Yassir, can you make the question a bit longer with the context of the notation? This will help focus in on what you mean.